# How to use CCCOMSTR and ASCOMSTR while compiling scons for user defined builder

Tags: scons

I am using **scons**. In my project I got a situation like to compile the `.src` files.

To compile them I have created a new builder. Code for new builder is

```cs
    asmcode_generator = Builder(action = '$ASCOM', single_source = 1,  suffix = '.obj')
    env.Append(BUILDERS = {'AsmCodeGenerator' : asmcode_generator})
```

And I am compiling the `.src` file with the above builder. Code is as below.

```cs
    sources = env.AsmCodeGenerator(service.src)
```

above code is working fine and generating the .obj file.

I want to print a String when an object file is generated.
for that I did the below.

```cs
     env['ASCOMSTR'] = "= Assembling $SOURCE "
```

But it is not printing this string while compiling.
The above code is working when an assembly file is compiled by scons builder.

can any one tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there is an action object with a command string (whatever $ASCOM evaluates to as a command line) and no build string (as you haven't specified one).

You need to create your own action object more completely, thus:

```
 asmcode_generate = Builder(action = Action('$ASCOM', 'Assembling $SOURCE'), ...)
```